# Finding and Replacing parts of person names

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column that consists of politician names which are extracted of thousands of news articles. Each row is a specific article. I want to count which politicians are mentioned the most, but count each name only one time per article (row).

The entities recognition algorithm returned these results. Now I have to convert the names in a standard form to be able to summarise and compare them.

Because there are maximal 20 people I am interested in, I knew the names and thought despite the effort,  manually coding the patterns for each name might be the fastest way (I am happy for other ideas).

```
#example-data 
persons <- c("Merkel,Angela Merkel,Trump,Ursula,Merkels", "Ursula von,Trumps,Donald Trump,Leyen") 
df <- data.frame(persons)

#change pattern
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
  persons= paste("  ",str_replace_all(df$persons,",", " , "), sep = "")
) 

#example of exctracting the names.. and so on, you get the idea
str_replace_all(df$persons, c("   Trump(s)?" = "Donald Trump", ", Trump(s)?" = ", Donald Trump", "Donald Trumps" = "Donald Trump",
                              "     Merkel(s)?") = "Angela Merkel")
```

My desired output is to have for each row just the full names. In the end I would remove the duplicated names per row and then I could count the dataset like desired.

The data would should look like this in the end:
`persons <- c("Angela Merkel,Angela Merkel,Donald Trump,Ursula von der Leyen,Angela Merkel", "Ursula von der Leyen,Donald Trump,Donald Trump,Ursula von der Leyen")`

I have especially a hard time with patterns for names which consists of more than two parts like  `Ursula von der Leyen`. **What would the best way to do convert the names and how would the pattern for replacement look like?**

**Edit**
I wrote now a function, witch takes care that there is only one instance of a name in my dataframe for each row. Not really elegant and nice code but its working.

```
clean_name <- function(x) {
  b <- unlist(strsplit(x, '[,]')) %>%
    str_squish(.)
  c <- b[!duplicated(b)]
  #Lists mit forename and surname
  ganzer_name <- vector()
  nachname<-vector()
for (person in c){
  if(any(str_count(person," ") == 0)){
    nachname <- append(nachname,person)
  } else{
    ganzer_name <- append(ganzer_name,person)
  }
}
  
#chckes if therese constructions like s wie Angela Merkels 
  ganzer_name <- ganzer_name%>%
    str_sort() %>% str_replace(.,"\\+","")
  i <-0
aussortieren <- c("","")

while(i < (length(ganzer_name)-1) ){
  i <- i+1
  if(str_detect(ganzer_name[i+1],
                paste0(ganzer_name[i],"*")
  )){
    aussortieren <- append(aussortieren, ganzer_name[i+1] )
  }else{  }
}

ganzer_name <- ganzer_name[!ganzer_name %in% aussortieren]
  
#check if surname is already in a full name
for( person in nachname ){
    #check construction with s like Merkels
      if(any(str_detect(ganzer_name, paste0(
        "\\Q",
        str_sub(person,end  = nchar(person)-1),
        "\\E" )  
                         )
             )  
      ) {
      } else {
        ganzer_name <- append(ganzer_name,person)
      }
    }
return(paste(ganzer_name, collapse=","))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of turning various combination of names into standard format, removing duplicates and then counting here is a different approach.

We can use `grepl` for pattern matching and count how many times a politician occurs in different news articles.

```
name <- c('Trump', 'Merkel')
sapply(name, function(x) sum(grepl(x, df$persons)))

# Trump Merkel 
#     2      1
```

Use `ignore.case = TRUE` in `grepl` if you want to make the comparison case insensitive.